# Stiff cloth/canvas like simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

Disclaimer: Im not very experienced with blender.

Ive been working on a little project for a video and i am inclined to use a cloth simulation for it. The subject of the video is filling a BigBag (Stiff plastic canvas fabric, [see this video for reference](https://youtu.be/DXiWNmjvSxI)).

So far i have a single layer surface cloth simulation, with some mball stuff to simulate filling it and deceiving the viewer with a particle system to emulate it filling.

However; the simulation does not look real enough. The fabric is flimsy and moves to much. Also, because it has zero thickness; it looks very... grocery bag like.

So im just looking for a way to take it to the next step!

A few things i need help with and tried myself:

- To give the bag some realism, i tried to solidify the body, it has a lot of self collision and really weird vertex hell.

  - Added some pressure to the inside, which made it look like everything but a bag.
  - To get an accurate sim, you need a lot of faces to correctly display. My current problem is that the amount of faces becomes very concentrated at the i.e. corners which then acts really weird with lets say pressure.
- Getting a stiff material.

  - I have been tweaking settings but they just do not make any sense at all. Is there a comprehensible guide that explains it? I have seen a lot of youtube video's but none really explain which setting does what.

Im currently also working at about x15 scale. I've read that that works with the bad self collisions etc.

Thats about it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you edit your question and add a screenshot of your work? How does the topology of the bag look like? Have you used a pin group? Here's a quick test I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p58FA.gif

Comment: Wow @Blunder, that is seriously impressive! Its actually what i am looking for. This following link is what i have so far: https://imgur.com/a/T9rbqT4 It doesnt work as i would want. Yours is more what im looking for, also the loops where it hangs on is a challenge for me. Does it still work with solidify on it? Sorry for the barrage of questions! Im just really excited. Oh and thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Yours looks great, too. If you want to make the bag stiffer you might reduce the number of vertices else you get this fine silk look. The loops should work with the Solidify modifier on them. I may post more details later.